# Angular 2 Value Providers - Values set from API call at initialization

Tags: dependency-injection, angular, angular2-services

I need to provide a date format to our application. We use this to set the format for all display and input of dates.

I need to provide this in numerous places to the application. However, the date varies depending on the client. We have an API call that provides a variety of settings (one of which is the date config) as a JSON object.

I want to be able to provide an object representing the configuration options as a value via DI. There are lots of examples of providing values, but they are all static rather than dynamic.

I want to do something like this in my DI composition root

```
provide('DateFormat', {
  useValue: 'dd/MM/yyyy'  
})
```

However, I want 'dd/MM/yyyy' to come from settings at startup.

I have tried providing it via services, but it is causing issues with race conditions in a few places (value not available when one service runs). Some of this could be solved by re-writing it using more observables, but it just makes the code more complex. So I want some way to provide the object via DI and have the values set before doing anything else.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you provide the service in the bootstrap, or in the providers:[] in the root component of your app it will instantiate the service. In the service constructor you can get the data via the api.

If you need to wait until it loads before the first page shows, you could have one observable that indicates the data is loaded or not. Use that observable to route to a new component by subscribing to the observable. Or depending on the structure of your app, use *ngIf on the boolean observable set by the service to show an initialization screen until the api call returns and the data is initialized.

Any other component that needs that configuration can use that instance of the service by injecting via the constructor args.

```
import {ConfigurationService} from 'path/to/configuration-service';

@Component({
    selector : '',
    providers: [ConfigurationService] <<-- This instantiates a new
    uninitialized service. Do this only in the root component.


})

export ComponentNeedingDateFormat() {
    constructor(private configurationService: ConfigurationService) { }
}
```

If you include it in component providers: [] it will instantiate a new service. You want to inject it only in the root component.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html